# Can't find() records from Play! application using mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm at the low end of the learning curve here, so please forgive the simplistic question.

I have set up my first Play application and have implemented their TodoList tutorial using a mongoDB database.  My code basically mirrors this code: https://github.com/Mironor/Play-2.0-Scala-MongoDb-Salat-exemple.

The application works fine, but when I use the command line, I can't find any records:

```
$ mongo
> show dbs 
local   (empty)
todo    0.0625GB
> db.todo.find()
> db.todo.tasks.find()
>
```

- I know the `todo` database is the one I want because when I drop it my data goes away.
- I know there are records in there because I can see them in the application
- I think I should find these records in `db.todo.tasks` because it is [specified by the model](https://github.com/Mironor/Play-2.0-Scala-MongoDb-Salat-exemple/blob/master/app/models/Task.scala)

So how do I find these records from the command line console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`todo` is the database, `tasks` is the collection.  Try this:

```
> use todo;
switched to db todo
> db.tasks.find();
```

In the MongoDB shell the `use` command is required to pick your database before you can query collections.  When you start the shell you're probably starting in the `test` db, so there's no way to get to your tasks from there.